# Nested Linear layout only shows first view after being set from gone to visible in Android

Tags: android, layout, visible

I am developing an Android app but I'm still pretty new. I want to have a button, and when you push that button, a few TextViews and Buttons will appear. So I have a main linear layout, and then another linear layout nested inside containing the things I want hidden. I have the nested linear layout set to android:visibility="gone".

The problem I am having is that it only shows the first item inside the hidden linear layout instead of all of them. The way I try to make it appear is

```
    vgAddView = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.add_details);

    btnAche.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            vgAddView.setVisibility(0);
        }
    });
```

My XML file is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<Button 
    android:text="@string/but_stomach_ache" 
    android:id="@+id/but_stomach_ache" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
<Button 
    android:text="@string/but_food" 
    android:id="@+id/but_food" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/add_details"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <TextView
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/when_happen">
        </TextView>
    <Button 
        android:text="@string/happen_now" 
        android:id="@+id/happen_now" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `TextView` in the `LinearLayout` is set to `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`, which means it will take up the entire space of the `LinearLayout`, leaving no room for the `Button`. If you use the [`hierarchyviewer`](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html) tool that shipped with the SDK, you can see that when you look at the activity.

You need to set the height of the `TextView` to be `wrap_content` or otherwise have it leave room for the `Button`.

Answer (score 1):

After you are setting its visibility to true set like below:

- `vgAddView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` - to show it
- `vgAddView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` - to hide it

Answer (score 0):

You first TextView has a layout_width="fill_parent".
It's mean,that you TextView don't leave space for Button.
You may try to set layout_weight attribute or set layout_width to wrap_content